# Xamarin Forms Firebase DeleteAsync logic - Why deletes first item instead of second item?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-storage

The thing is doing in my code is when I delete the 2nd block without deleting the first one, the one that is being deleted is the first one and not the selected 2nd block."

```
    //This is where the listview item tapped
       var certification = args.Item as Certifications;
        if (certification == null) return;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new CertificationDetailsPage(certification));
        lstCertifications.SelectedItem = null;

    // This is the code to delete
       var toDeleteCertification = (await client
            .Child("Table => Certifications")
            .OnceAsync<Certifications>()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Object.FullName == fullName || a.Object.Email == email || a.Object.Address == address
            || a.Object.Occupation == occupation || a.Object.Age == age || a.Object.Sex == sex || a.Object.CivilStatus == civilStatus
            || a.Object.Date == date || a.Object.TypeofCertificate == typeofCertificate || a.Object.Purpose == purpose);
        await client.Child("Table => Certifications").Child(toDeleteCertification.Key).DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: I can't tell from this what is happening. Show a small, complete, example. Show the two items being added. Then, write a *test* that, in code, deletes the 2nd block. Does that test code work? If it doesn't, then it has nothing to do with which item is tapped; you need to isolate exactly what is wrong in your code. That's quite a lengthy expression in the delete code - *you* need to find out *exactly* what you did wrong. Do this by building it up, one bit at a time, using hardcoded test logic to see if it is doing what you expect.

Comment: ... odds are, this has nothing to do with "FireBase DeleteAsync" per se; just some simple mistake or misunderstanding in writing that delete expression. Happens to all of us; learning how to **isolate** a bug down to the exact cause is a huge part of mastering code writing. :)

Comment: Thank you very much ToolmakerSteve!!! I focused on the deletion part and instead of '||', I changed it to '&&' then now it is normal and working as planned. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting this answer here, to confirm that Beginnerton solved their problem.

It was a logic mistake in the delete expression; needed `&&` instead of `||`.